# Cancel WMI event notification created with ExecNotificationQuery

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I can create non-permanent WMI event queries in script, such as this one, which logs the PIDs of the next 5 new Notepad.exe processes:

```vb
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\ROOT\cimv2")

wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 " & _ 
      "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name = 'Notepad.exe'"
Set EventSource = WMI.ExecNotificationQuery(wql)

For i = 1 To 5
    With EventSource.NextEvent(-1)
        Wscript.Echo .TargetInstance.ProcessId
    End With
Next
```

But I'm missing a way of explicitly canceling the `EventSource`. Without that, the event notification will continue to run indefinitely inside the WMI, even if the script that listens for the generated events terminates for whatever reason<sup>(*)</sup>. This would lead to increasing build-up of overhead when the script is run multiple times.

MSDN [documentation of `IWbemServices::ExecNotificationQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nf-wbemcli-iwbemservices-execnotificationquery) says:

> The **IWbemServices::ExecNotificationQuery** method executes a query to receive events. The call returns immediately, and the user can poll the returned enumerator for events as they arrive. Releasing the returned enumerator cancels the query.

How do I release the returned enumerator?

The `EventSource` object does not seem to be enumerable. Trying to use `For Each` on it fails with *"VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"*, so I can't use the implicit `Release` at the end of a `For Each` loop.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> This follows from the documentation stating that *"Releasing the returned enumerator cancels the query."*, which implies that *not* releasing the enumerator causes the query to persist - but it can be confirmed explicitly, too:

Set up a notification for this query `"SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Directory' And TargetInstance.Name = 'C:\\Test'"` and use [Sysinternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to observe file system accesses from the WMI service (`WmiPrvSE.exe`). The WMI service will start polling for folders named "C:\Test" every 2 seconds, and it will continue doing so after the script that set up the monitoring has ended.

Restarting the WMI Service gets rid of the polling, but obviously that's not a good solution for this situation.

Comment: What about `Set EventSource = Nothing`?

Comment: @user692942 No, that doesn't help. This happens anyway when the script exits. But WMI event queries are like this: You send a query to the WMI service. The WMI service internally sets up monitoring for the requested condition and returns a way to listen for the generated events. Setting the event listener to `Nothing` in the VBScript will not tear down the WMI-internal part of the mechanism.

Comment: Yeah, but this isn’t a permanent event consumer you are setting up it’s a temporary one, they don’t work the same way. Which is why [most examples use an infinite do while loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemservices-execnotificationquery) to stop the script from exiting usually with a script delay. Have you worked out that the event listener is being held after the script finishes or is it just an assumption?

Comment: The event notification is temporary in the sense that it does not survive a restart of the WMI service. It does survive the end of the script that created it. WMI events are a polling mechanism. `.NextEvent()` will block the script until the WMI provides another event. The WMI does not care if anyone is polling the created events, it creates them anyway. The internal event creation must be cancelled explicitly.

Comment: Looking at your most recent edit it sounds like it is holding on to the event, so you probably want to call [`ExecNotificationQueryAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemservices-execnotificationqueryasync) and pass in [the sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemsink) and [cancel that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nf-wbemcli-iwbemservices-cancelasynccall?redirectedfrom=MSDN). I'm no expert on WMI stuff by any stretch, I was simply providing suggestions.

Comment: Maybe this will help - [Monitoring Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/monitoring-events).

Comment: So, I think the answer is you can't. The wording used in the documentation is very vague and the other article I posted doesn't make that part any clearer. It seems is almost treated as a non-issue, as a temporary event consumer will only be around until the next reboot or manual recycle of the WMI service.

Comment: @user692942 Nope, you had the right idea. Canceling the asynchronous sink actually does it. Nice. :) Can you turn that into an answer?

Comment: Glad it's now working for you, an interesting one because I didn't realise that temporary event consumers persisted past the script execution as most examples run in an infinite loop, which was an assumption on my part.

Comment: Releasing the event source cancels the notification query. Try it. @user692942 was correct the first time. You should try things instead of just arguing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use [`ExecNotificationQueryAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemservices-execnotificationqueryasync) instead? That way you can pass it a [`SWbemSink` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemsink) that you can later call [`Cancel()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemsink-cancel) on to cancel the sink which should also remove any event consumer associated with that sink.

The problem with using the `ExecNotificationQuery()` method is it only gives you access to a `SWbemEventSource` object which allows calling the next event in the enumerator. It doesn't seem possible to use that method to remove the event consumer once it is registered.

Running this:

```vb
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\ROOT\cimv2")
Set Sink = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemSink", "Sink_")

wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 " & _
      "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Directory' And TargetInstance.Name = 'C:\\Test'"

WScript.Echo "Waiting for events..."
WMI.ExecNotificationQueryAsync Sink, wql

For i = 1 To 10
    WScript.Echo i
    Wscript.Sleep 1000
    If i = 5 Then
        FSO.CreateFolder "C:\Test"
        WScript.Echo "Test folder created."
    End If
Next

Sink.Cancel
WScript.Echo "Sink canceled."

FSO.DeleteFolder "C:\Test"
WScript.Echo "Test folder deleted."

Sub Sink_OnObjectReady(eventObject, asyncContext)
    Set folder = eventObject.TargetInstance
    WScript.Echo "__InstanceCreationEvent: " & folder.Name
End Sub
```

outputs something similar to this:

```
Waiting for events...
1
2
3
4
5
Test folder created.
6
7
__InstanceCreationEvent: C:\Test
8
9
10
Sink canceled.
Test folder deleted.
```

After that, Process Monitor will confirm that WMI has stopped background polling for folder creation.

Caveat: It's absolutely essential that `Sink.Cancel` is called. If the script terminates unexpectedly, WMI *will* continue to poll in the background, and restarting the WMI service is the only way to get rid of the polling loop.

Comment: Glad this worked out, excellent example thanks for adding it to the answer.

Comment: Too bad that there seems to be no resilient way of doing this with VBScript. I wonder if PowerShell would be able to do a better job.